# retain entries in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have the following (view) controller arrangement:

an uitableview --(embedded in)--> navigation controller --(embedded in)--> Tab bar controller --(modal segue to)--> button in a view (uiviewcontroller).

description of my problem:

The view with the button is the initial view of my app. Pressing this button leads to a tableview in a tab bar. At the beginning the table view is empty, but you can manually add information on the cells, like names. However, once you go back to initial view (with button) and press the button again, the previous entries in the table view are erased.Can somebody give a hint how to retain these entries with the given arrangement. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Paste some code when you click the button.

Comment: My wild guess is that you're creating a new view controller when you segue back to the view with the table in it, but like Jacky Boy says, we needs some code!

Comment: Please show the code of the model behind your table view. There's probably a mutable array somewhere, and the new entries go there. Please tell us where that array is declared, and how it is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the singleton pattern. It will create a shared instance of your object, that you can access anywhere. You will then be able to write in it when the user adds a row in the table, and read it when you come to the tableView.

Here is a bit of help : [Singleton pattern](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/global-variables-in-iphone-objective-c/)

**EDIT :** you can also use core data, but it may not be appropriate in your situation (plenty of docs on the web about that one)

Comment: This could be the solution. Thank you very much. Yes, I'm currently hammering core data into my head.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a question as it really isn't about the interface per se. It is more to do with general Object Orientated Programming and the life time of objects.

Basically your data needs to be stored higher up the object hierarchy. It needs to persist across construction/destruction of the interface objects. This could also be done by storing the data in persist-able data store such as a DB or file but you would still need to store the means to extract the data or subset of data from the store.

If you wish to persist the data you could store data in a singleton data class and reference it statically  or store it in your UIApplication object and pass that down the hierarchy as you create each object. you would probably have to subclass each object and add a new constructor passing in a ref to the data.

Comment: I anticipated that I have to do something like what you have described. And yes, I am intending to persistently store these entry data. Thank you very much for you answer.